# Android - Auto Complete not showing when using AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have an `EditText` in my app. This properly shows the Auto Complete bar at the top of the Google Keyboard when typing as seen below:

[image: Properly Working Auto Complete]

I also have an AutoCompleteTextView. This doesn't have an AutoComplete function at all on the keyboard as shown below:

[image: Improperly Working Auto Complete]

How come `AutoCompleteTextView`s do not use AutoComplete by default while `EditText`s do? Also, how can I turn this feature on in my `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Thanks in advance!